# Natural Gas Fireplace rust starting at flue inside house, should i be worried ? What can i do to fix?

Tags: fireplace, rust

[image]

Having a hard time finding information online about my situation.
Only owners manual I don't have for the appliances in my house.
Luxors Gas fires - Model - MB-36

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how to participate here.

Comment: rust = water leak, so, has the chimney or cap been inspected by you or anyone else?

Comment: Is is possible that rainwater is coming down the flue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using any gas appliance water is a byproduct of the combustion process. Under normal conditions, this is expelled through the vent into the atmosphere and does not cause any
harm. In cold weather however, the vapors may condense on any exposed surface it comes into contact with.

I think your flue is colder than the fire place and condensation is occurring when the hot wet air contacts the cold flue surface. It's happening everywhere on the flue but it's only an issue where rust can also occur. The rust is occurring around the connection between the pipe and firebox evidenced by the rust near the top of the pipe that would not occur if water was draining down the inside of the pipe. Also the inside of the pipe is clean. The edge of the opening in the firebox for the pipe may have had its protective coat of paint damaged during the instillation, or wasn't applied very thick during manufacture.

It's an issue because it doesn't look nice and eventually it will rust through. To prevent future rusting you can paint the affected area with paint, sanding first off any rust or rust stains. You just need to do the area around the pipe. You need paint that is heat resistant. It will say so on the container.

Comment: My take - It looks to me that the water isn't coming from inside that vent - no rust there. I think OP is going to find that some caulk is needed on the exterior.

Comment: The water is everywhere in that area from condensation. It's not coming 'from somewhere' and even if it were, you don't see rust unless there's rust, there could be water flow that dried up nice and clean. We are only seeing signs of it where there is an issue with protection of the metal. The rust and stain is a telltale. The water is normal(ish). The real issue is that the metal is not properly protected.

Comment: ...and I'm going to reevaluate and concede that I might be off, you have a very valid point @HoneyDo, it could very well be water flowing down the outside of the flue pipe and into the fire box. And they do need to eliminate the possibility of a leak at the chimney as the first part of the troubleshooting process

Comment: "flue is colder than the fire place and condensation is occurring when the hot wet air contacts the cold flue surface" @Ack I was on the idea that this was the issue. Inside the Direct Vent to the outdoors I don't see any rust its only where its seen in the picture. I was able to see the connection above where the flexible ducting connects to firebox with inspection mirror ( cant see much ) but looks like rust around connection of firebox.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you may need to reseal around the exterior portion of your fireplace vent where it exits your house.. It doesn't appear that anything has rusted through but don't wait to weatherize it. Once it rusts out it's going to require replacing the vent.

Comment: By exterior I think you mean where it exits the structure rather than where it exits the firebox. This might be clear to everyone else but wasn't to me

Comment: Both. I'm just saying that from the photo it appears that the moisture may be flowing down the exterior of the flue pipe not the interior. If that is true the odds are that the weatherseal on the flue exterior should be inspected for leaks.

Comment: @Ack You made a good point.I edited my answer to be a little clearer.